# Using JDBC to call a PL/SQL stored procedure with custom type input parameter, all fields are null

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, java-8

I'm using JDBC with `createStruct()` to call a stored procedure on an Oracle database that accepts a custom type as a parameter. The stored procedure inserts the custom type fields into a table and when I `SELECT` from the table later I see that all the fields that I tried to insert are `NULL`.

The custom type looks like this:

```
type record_rec as object (owner_id varchar2 (7),
                                        target_id VARCHAR2 (8),
                                        IP VARCHAR2 (15),
                                        PREFIX varchar2 (7),
                                        port varchar2 (4),
                                        description VARCHAR2 (35),
                                        cost_id varchar2(10))
```

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
package body            "PKG_RECORDS"
IS
procedure P_ADD_RECORD (p_target_id in out VARCHAR2,
                      p_record_rec in record_rec)
is
  l_target_id   targets.target_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  Insert into targets (target_id,
                      owner_id,
                      IP,
                      description,
                      prefix,
                      start_date,
                      end_date,
                      cost_id,
                      port,
                      server_name,
                      server_code)
       values (f_sequence ('TARGETS'),
               p_record_rec.owner_id,
               p_record_rec.ip,
               p_record_rec.description,
               p_record_rec.prefix,
               sysdate,
               to_date ('01-JAN-2050'),
               p_record_rec.cost_id,
               p_record_rec.port,
               'test-server',
               '51')
    returning target_id
         into p_target_id;
 END;
END PKG_RECORDS;
```

My Java code looks something like this:

```
try (Connection con = m_dataSource.getConnection()) {
    ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    CallableStatement call = con.prepareCall("{call PKG_RECORDS.P_ADD_RECORD(?,?)}");
    for (Record r : records) {
        call.registerOutParameter("p_target_id", Types.VARCHAR);
        call.setObject("p_record_rec", 
                con.createStruct("SCHEME_ADM.RECORD_REC", new Object[] {
                        r.getTarget_id(),
                        null, // will be populated by SP
                        t.getIp(),
                        t.getPrefix(),
                        t.getPort(),
                        t.getDescription(),
                        t.getCost_id()
                }), Types.STRUCT);
        call.execute();
        ids.add(call.getString("p_target_id"));
    }

    return new QueryRunner().query(con, 
            "SELECT * from TARGETS_V WHERE TARGET_ID IN ("+
                    ids.stream().map(s -> "?").collect(Collectors.joining(",")) +
                    ")",
            new BeanListHandler<Record>(Record.class),
            ids.toArray(new Object[] {})
            ).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new DataAccessException(e.getMessage());
}
```

Notes:
 * That last part is using Apache Commons db-utils - I love their bean stream operations.
 * The connection is using C3P0 connection pool - could that be related?
 * Just to make it clear - its not that the bean processor populates null values into the `Record` bean fields - if I use an SQL explorer to load the table (or view) directly, I can see that the fields in the database are indeed set to `NULL`.

There are no `SQLException`s when the process runs, or any other notice that something is wrong.

Any ideas what to check?

**[Update]**
After reading on Oracle Objects and SQLData mappings, I rewrote the code to use [SQLData](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraoot.htm#JJDBC28449).

The `Record` class now implements `SQLData` and it's `writeSQL()` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
    stream.writeString(owner_id);
    stream.writeString(target_id);
    stream.writeString(Objects.isNull(ip) ? "0" : ip); // weird, but as specified
    stream.writeString(prefix);
    stream.writeString(String.valueOf(port));
    stream.writeString(description);
    stream.writeString(cost_id);
}
```

Then at the start of the calling code, I've added:

```
con.getTypeMap().put("SCHEME_ADM.RECORD_REC", Record.class);
```

And instead of using `createStruct()`, the `setObject()` call now looks simply like this:

```
call.setObject("p_record_rec", t, Types.STRUCT)
```

But the result is the same - no errors and all the passed values are read as `NULL`. I've traced through the `writeSQL()` implementation and I can see that it is called and all values are passed correctly into the Oracle code. I've tried to use `Types.JAVA_OBJECT` in the `setObject()` call, and got an error: `Invalid column type`.

**[Update 2]**
Bordering on insane helplessness I've implemented the [`OracleData` pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraoot.htm#JJDBC28466):

```
public class Record implements SQLData, OracleData, OracleDataFactory {
...
@Override
public Object toJDBCObject(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    return conn.createStruct(getSQLTypeName(), new Object[] {
            Objects.isNull(owner_id) ? "" : owner_id,
            Objects.isNull(record_id) ? "" : record_id,
            Objects.isNull(ip) ? "0" : ip,
            Objects.isNull(prefix) ? "" : prefix,
            String.valueOf(port),
            Objects.isNull(description) ? "" : description,
            Objects.isNull(cost_id) ? "" : cost_id
    });
}

@Override
public OracleData create(Object jdbcValue, int sqltype) throws SQLException {
    if (Objects.isNull(jdbcValue)) return null;
    LinkedList<Object> attr = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(((OracleStruct)jdbcValue).getAttributes()));
    Record r = new Record();
    r.setOwner_id(attr.removeFirst().toString());
    r.setRecord_id(attr.removeFirst().toString());
    r.setIp(attr.removeFirst().toString());
    r.setPrefix(attr.removeFirst().toString());
    r.setPort(Integer.parseInt(attr.removeFirst().toString()));
    r.setDescription(attr.removeFirst().toString());
    r.setCost_id(attr.removeFirst().toString());
    return r;
}

public static OracleDataFactory getOracleDataFactory() {
    return new Record();
}
```

Calling code:

```
...
// unwrap the Oracle object from C3P0 (standard JDBCv4 API)
OracleCallableStatement ops = call.unwrap(OracleCallableStatement.class);
// I'm not sure why I even need to do this - it looks exactly like
// the standard JDBC code
for (Records r : records) {
    ops.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    ops.setObject(2, t);
    ops.execute();
    ids.add(ops.getString(1));
}
...
```

And again, same result - no errors, a record is created in the table, with all provided values are null. I've traced through the code and the `toJDBCObject()` method is called correctly and does pass the values correctly in to `createStruct()`.

Comment: You might try changing `p_record_rec` to `P_RECORD_REC` in your call to setObject. All Oracle identifiers are UPPER_CASE unless specifically quoted. I'd expect an exception to be raised if this was really the issue, but it won't hurt anything to try it. Best of luck.

Comment: Idk, the SP definition is in lower case. Regardless, I tried - no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Annoyingly, its about character encoding.

If in the `toJDBCObject()` implementation, I run `getAttributes()` on the created struct, the resulting `Object[]` array has all fields set as `"???"`. Which is weird and looks like a character set transcoding failure (although it looks weird for that too - has three question marks for all fields regardless of value length, including empty string values).

According to [Oracle's JDBC developer guide, "Globalization Support"](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28644):

> The basic Java Archive (JAR) file ojdbc7.jar, contains all the necessary classes to provide complete globalization support for:
>
> - Oracle character sets for CHAR, VARCHAR, LONGVARCHAR, or CLOB data that is not being retrieved or inserted as a data member of an **Oracle object** or collection type.
> - **CHAR or VARCHAR data members of object** and collection for the character sets US7ASCII, WE8DEC, WE8ISO8859P1, WE8MSWIN1252, and UTF8.
>
> To use any other character sets in CHAR or VARCHAR data members of objects or collections, you must include orai18n.jar in the CLASSPATH environment variable:
>
> `ORACLE_HOME/jlib/orai18n.jar`

And my setup was using the character set "`WE8ISO8859P9`" (I have no idea why, what it means, or even if it is selected by the client or the server - I just dumped the `STRUCT` object created by the `OracleData` API implementation and it was there somewhere).

So when Oracle says that it does not "*provide complete globalization support*", they mean "*all character fields will be silently converted to `NULL`*". Hmpph.

Anyway, adding `orai18n.jar` to the `CLASSPATH` indeed fixed the problem, and now records are added correctly to the database.